How to change default location of Resource.h in Visual Studio C++?
I've been developing an application on my spare time just to get some practice and keep my programming skills sharp.
As a result, I've been challenging myself to deal with the WinAPI while using Visual Studio.
Starting a new project basically dumps everything you would need to get started in one folder, so to organize things a bit I thought it would be handy to throw all the generated files in a folder appropriately named API.
Trying to recompile, it tells me there is an error since it couldn't find targetver.h (since it is now in the API folder). After clicking around a bunch, I found where I can change it so that I can change the path for the include of targetver.h.
Here is the issue:
When I'm making changes to the Dialog boxes using the Resource View with Visual Studio, it seems to regenerate the resource.h file and place it in the root directory.
Also, it regenerates the default images in the root directory, even though I've already included them in another folder for the media to live in. I've also told the compiler about the added directories, and included them in my project's "Additional Include Directories".
How can I change the default location for these files to be generated?

" included them in my projects Addition Include Directories."  I think this is where you went wrong - this should not be needed. After moving files to a new directory (or a new drive), I usually delete the one in the Solution Explorer and then drag them back in from their new directory. (You can drag from the File Explorer into the Solution Explorer, and those files will be added to the project).
